# Sci fi women in a prison or captured

Tags: story-identification

I keep remembering this movie about a group of women locked up in a sci fi looking prison or something and they have to escape but they use their imagination and it unlocks how they are to escape. Lots of clues and they are like in different worlds while they are in this prison. I was waiting for it to come onto DVD and I guess I forgot and life happened I guess.

Comment: Sounds like a great nsfw entertainment video to me.

Comment: “Not quite sure what it is but my question was answered” — [it’s a question and answer site](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Caution: don't overthink the movie.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This sounds sort of like [Sucker Punch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sucker_Punch_%282011_film%29).

The movie deals with a group of young girls being held in a mental hospital where they are victimized by the staff.

As a means of coping, the main character creates elaborate scenarios in her head. Each scenario corresponds to a mission the girls undertake to acquire an item necessary to aid in their escape from the hospital.

The envisioned scenarios include things like battling dragons, giant samurai warriors, and zombie nazis, amongst other things.

[image: Poster]

Comment: Wow. This question was nonsense to me, but this answer really cleared it up. Poorly worded question, great parsing.

Comment: The trailer for this for so awesome. The movie just couldn't live up to it